# SystemConfigurationException Read Only properties.settings.default.save()

Tags: windows, settings, readonly

The above error recently started being thrown when I was making updates to an existing C# windows app that saves a folder location for files it uses.

Upon receiving this error, I found that my whole hard drive seems to be set to read only. (recently had to build a new dev system) I have tried changing the folders back to being readable via folder properties. Dialog pops up and goes through all the files as if it were changing the properties.  When I open the properties immediately after, the folder is back to read only.

I have also noticed that VS IDE does't save changes to the recent files/projects.

Anyone experience this and have the solution?

Things I have tried:

- created a new admin user. Logged in and found the same situation.  Not tied to my profile.
- Tried command prompt changing folder attributes with attrib command.
- Tried changing my users permissions to full control.
- uninstalled OneDrive  (to eliminate possible syncing issues)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my AppData folder hidden property was set to true.  Setting this folder and all sub folders to not be hidden fixes everything.